# Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: YES) SQLState: 28000 VendorError: 1045 : How to solve the problem?

Tags: mysql, jdbc

I am new to make experiment with MYSQL and JDBC. But I am stuck at the very beginning. I could load the Connector/j driver but unable to connect to the database. I am using Eclipse on windows. I am able to connect to the database using MYSQL shell using same user id and password. Here follows the program and the output:

````
```   

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class Medical {

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Connection conn = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Cannot Load the Driver!"); 
            System.out.println("SQLException: " + ex.getMessage());         
        }
        try {
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/medical" + 
                    "?name=chayan&password='password'&useSSL=false");
            System.out.println("Connected!");

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println("Could not connect to the database!");
            System.out.println("SQLException: " + ex.getMessage());
            System.out.println("SQLState: " + ex.getSQLState());
            System.out.println("VendorError: " + ex.getErrorCode());
        }
    }
}

```
````

Output:

> Could not connect to the database! 
>   SQLException: Access denied for > user ''@'localhost' (using password: YES) 
>   SQLState: 28000 
>   VendorError: 1045

Could anyone help?

Comment: Have you tried replacing `name=chayan` in the connection string with `user=chayan`?

Comment: conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/medical" + 
                    "?user=chayan&password=password&useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true"); This solved my problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi @daschay I think your jdbc url is not as the [reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-usagenotes-connect-drivermanager.html) said,

field `name` should be `user` and password should not use quotation marks

try to change `getConnection` line to this

```
conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/medical" + 
                    "?user=chayan&password=password&useSSL=false");
```

hope this help

Comment: Yes this helped. I had to additionally add allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true. Thank you.

Comment: then could you pls accept my answer @daschay
- thanks -